# Two data from user to make Calculation using PHP

Tags: php

May I know how exactly equation in PHP works? All my data can be extracted well, but how can I get two data fromuser which are `$method=$_GET['method'];` and `$valueinsert=$_GET['valueinsert'];`.

```
$valueinsert=$_GET['valueinsert'];
                        $method=$_GET['method'];
                        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
                        //connect to the server
                        $connect= mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
                        //$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
                        if(!$connect)
                        {
                        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error($connect));
                        }
                        //connect to the database
                        mysql_select_db("fyp",$connect);

                        $query5 = "SELECT method, SUM(revenue), SUM(cost) FROM `table 1` WHERE method = '$method'"; 
                        $result5 = mysql_query($query5) or die(mysql_error());

                        $sql="SELECT * FROM `table 1` WHERE method='$method'";
                        $query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);

                        echo"<table align=center width='80%'>";
                            echo"<td valign='top' width='20%'> ";
                            echo "<b><u>$method </u></b>" ;
                                echo "</br>";
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result5)){
                                    echo "Total Profit = RM ". round($row['SUM(revenue)']- ($row['SUM(cost)']- '$valueinsert' ) ,2);
                                    echo "<br />";
                                }

                        echo"</table>";
                        ?>
```

Comment: Look at your array structure and you will know the indices to use (`print_r($row)` or `var_dump($row)`). You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Each column retrieved from the database is an individual column `($row['SUM(Revenue)'] - $row['SUM(cost)']) / $row['SUM(Revenue)']`

Comment: You tried to round it ? `round($row['(SUM(Revenue)-SUM(cost))/SUM(Revenue)'],2);` ?

Comment: You should start with watching or reading some php tuts before going any further. Your example reflects deep misunderstanding on how type casting, array indices, pointers, and superglobals work. Go learn a bit, then come back and we'll answer.

Comment: First, you query is wrong. You need a `group by Method` at end, also, if you didn't define any alias to your fields you should use then as is, so `SUM(Revenue)` != `SUM(revenue)` Better ways is to define aliases like: `SELECT Method, SUM(cost) as sumCost,  SUM(revenue) sumRevenue` and use these aliases in your php code. Also consider in changing your `mysql_*` for `mysqli_*` or PDO `mysql_*` function are deprecated.

Comment: As @chris85 points out you are open to SQL injection by using the depreciated mysql_ functions. You should be using mysqli_ or PDO.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the result directly in sql too

```
  "SELECT 
    Method
  , SUM(cost) as cost
  , SUM(revenue) as revenue
  , (SUM(Revenue)-SUM(cost))/SUM(Revenue) as result  
  FROM `table 1` 
  WHERE Method = '$Method'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to this

**Method 1**

```
$query4 = "SELECT Method, SUM(cost) as cost, SUM(revenue) as revenue FROM `table 1` WHERE Method = '$Method'";
```

And also in fetching the result side. Should be like this

```
   echo "Total Gross Margin = RM ". round($row['revenue']- $row['cost'] / $row['revenue'],2);
```

**Method 2**

```
echo "Total Gross Margin = RM ". round($row['(SUM(Revenue)-SUM(cost))/SUM(Revenue)'],2);
```